# Number of partitions scanned (=1000) on table 'table' exceeds limit (=100)

Tags: apache-spark

All queries for table fail with this error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Number of partitions scanned (=1000) on table 'table' exceeds limit (=100). This is controlled on the metastore server by metastore.limit.partition.request.)

spark.table("table").
filter($"dt" === "2023-01-01").
show
```

I have these configs for spark-shell

```
--conf spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=false \
--conf spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=true \
```

Spark seems to be scanning the whole table despite the filter and the configs. Why does this happen? My table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table(
columns ...
PARTITIONED BY (dt date)
STORED AS ORC
TBLPROPERTIES (external.table.purge'='true', orc.compress'='ZLIB')
```

Comment: I tried it in hive it runs ok. Still I need it to work in spark too.

Answer (score -1):

You should set the [`hive.metastore.limit.partition.request`(see docs)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/configuration+properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.metastore.limit.partition.request) property (as the error says). The default values is `-1` (*unlimited*), but probably your spark config sets that value somewhere.

To set hive properties in Spark you need to prefix them with `spark.sql.` (as you already do in your example.

Comment: Setting `--conf spark.sql.hive.metastore.limit.partition.request` to -1 or 10000 when initializing spark-shell doesn't help(same error) and I don't have permissions to modify cluster settings.

Comment: Maybe try setting the `--conf spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.limit.partition.request=-1`. I have seen that's how our clusters are configured (databricks). You can also verify the hadoop config with `sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get("hive.metastore.limit.partition.request")` (There's a difference between the `spark.conf` and the `sc.hadoopConfig`).

Comment: This didn't help either. Further testing showed some details. If I recreate the table with column `dt` as a string and run any select, it works. The problem is in the partition column. Execution plan shows a cast is happening in the filter. Might be some bug.

Comment: Which spark version are you using?

Comment: Maybe it's the https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-36876? It has only been fixed in spark `3.3.0`.

Comment: spark 2.2. Tried altering column type. Hive failed. The issue was solved by asking the admins to temporarily increase the limit and runnig alter table. Execution plan now shows  `[isnotnull(time_key#126), (time_key#126 = 2022-01-01)]` Will have to test again when the limit is lowered.